# Trying to paste values of array into variable

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oop

Currently I'm stuck on how to add the values of my array into a variable, to output in a query.

Here are my data stored in:

```
try {

    $link->create(array(

        'uid'       =>  $user->data()->id,
        'name'      =>  Input::get('name'),
        'hyperlink' =>  Input::get('hyperlink')

    ));

} catch (Exception $e) {

    die($e->getMessage());

}
```

And with this function I'm trying to get the values from that array into 1 variable:

```
    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {

        if (count($fields)) {

            $keys = array_keys($fields);

            $x = 1;

            foreach ($fields as $field => $values) {

                if ($x < count($fields)) {

                    $values .= ', ';

                }

                $x++;

            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

            die($sql);

            if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {

                return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }
```

But when I echo the sql it only gives the last value of the array. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: $values = $values; overwriting stuff are ya?

Comment: Edited: was for testing purpose.. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Kind of nasty to use a variable that you are using inside the loop, right?! As in, $values is re-assigned inside the loop..

Comment: Is SQL injection a threat?

Comment: Is it vulnerable to sql-injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, cuts down on the looping a bit, and could be combined into a single line actually...   EDIT: neglected to quote the values... updated appropriately

```
if (count($fields)) {

  $field_list = implode(", ", array_keys($fields));
  $value_list = implode("', '", array_values($fields));

  $sql =  "insert into `$table` ($field_list) values('$value_list')";

}
```

Comment: Thanks, very easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option and I couldn't figure out what was wrong with your script, it looks correct but wasn't able to find the problem. I always use this class method when inserting db values dynamically.

```
   function insertRecord ($fieldarray)
   {
      $this->errors = array();


      //Connect to the DB for table insert
      global $dbconnect, $query;
      $dbconnect = db_connect($this->dbname) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

     //Now, using the contents of $fieldlist which was set in the class constructor we can edit the input array to filter out any items which do not belong in this database table. This removes the SUBMIT button, for example.

      $fieldlist = $this->fieldlist;
      foreach ($fieldarray as $field => $fieldvalue) {
         if (!in_array($field, $fieldlist)) {
            unset ($fieldarray[$field]);
         } // if
      } // foreach

      //Now construct the query string to insert a new 
      //record into the database:

      $query = "INSERT INTO $this->tablename SET ";
      foreach ($fieldarray as $item => $value) {
         $query .= "$item='$value', ";
      } // foreach

      //You may have noticed that each 'name=value' pair was appended 
      //to the query string with a trailing comma as a separator, 
      //so we   must remove the final comma like so:

      $query = rtrim($query, ', ');

      //Now execute the query. Notice here that instead of the default 
      //error checking I look specifically for a 'duplicate key' error  
      //and return a simple error message rather terminating the whole   
      //script with a fatal error.

      $result = @mysql_query($query, $dbconnect);
      if (mysql_errno() <> 0) {
         if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
            $this->errors[] = "A record already exists with this ID.";
         } else {
            trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
         } // if
      } // if

      //Last act is to return control to the calling script.

      return;

   } // insertRecord
```

IMHO the function above has the necessary checks for an insert statement and error handling which I found useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the function array_values like you use the function array_keys to do this easier.

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {

        if (count($fields)) {

            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = array_values($fields); // why another logic for the same result.. ?

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES (`" . implode('`, `', $values) . "`)";

            die($sql);

            if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {

                return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `$values = $values` is inside the foreach loop.

```
foreach ($fields as $field => $values) {
    // The problem is right here, each time this loops, you are
    // setting the entire $values variable to be just the current iteration
    // of the $fields variable.

    $values = $values;

    if ($x < count($fields)) {

        $values .= ', ';

    }

    $x++;

}
```

Try this instead:

```
$sql_values = '';
foreach ($fields as $field => $values) {

    if ($x < count($fields)) {

        $sql_values.= $values.', ';

    }

    $x++;

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ($sql_values)";
```

Comment: Did you forget to append `$values` to `$sql_values`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - good call.  I totally forgot.  Not that it matters anyway as there are several correct answers that were submitted at the same time.